# how to reset a variable after using in function angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have defined variable type number `IndexCounter = 0;`

This is the function that I wrote:

```
counter() {
  for(let i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
    this.IndexCounter = i++;
  }

  return ++this.IndexCounter;       
  this.IndexCounter = 0;
}
```

And this is the problem that i got:

> Unreachable code detected

Comment: Please learn the basic concepts of programming before posting questions to SO. This is day 1 lesson you are missing. And please use propper tags. This is not C#. Is this Typescript? Please edit your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the warning is that code *after* a return-statement can´t be executed at all, the return-statement should be the last one within your method (or within the execution-branch, to be more exact).

Just store the number before you reset it:

```
counter() 
{
    for(let i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
        this.IndexCounter = i++;
    }
    let val = this.IndexCounter++; 
    this.IndexCounter = 0;
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value you want to return to a new variable and reset the original variable:

```
counter() {
  for(let i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
      this.IndexCounter = i++;
  }
  let result = this.IndexCounter++;
  this.IndexCounter = 0;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `return` must always be the last statement in a scope. You can't put something after a return in the same scope.

You should do:

```
counter() {
    for(let i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
        this.IndexCounter = i++;
    }
    var out = ++this.IndexCounter;
    this.IndexCounter = 0;
    return out;
}
```

---

Explanation:

You can return in a scope as long as there are no other code after it. A scope is defined by the need to put `{}` (curly braces) around something.

Example of returning in an `if` statement:

```
function isTrue(arg){
    if(arg === true){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which would return 0